# Extremely simple android app keeps FC'ing

Tags: android, forceclose

Hey I just started dabbling with android programming, and from my short period of time with it I'm a bit frustrated. I can get no errors in eclipse, but when I start my app it immediately force closes. I'm following an android tutorial book verbatim, and still I'm getting errors. My aim here is to create a list view inside a relative layout. Also, for some reason when I assign p.firstName or p.lastName it'll force close as well, but anyways here's my code. I'm using API level 15 (ie. Android 4.0.3) if that makes a difference.

```
 package matthews.zack.test;
 import android.app.Activity;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.view.View;
 import android.widget.Button;
 import android.widget.EditText;
   public class _testActivity extends Activity {

Button save;
People p = new People();
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    //onInitialize();
}

private void onInitialize()
{
     save = (Button)findViewById(android.R.id.button1);
     save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {


        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            EditText firstName = (EditText)findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
            EditText lastName = (EditText)findViewById(android.R.id.text2);
            p.setFirstName("Hai");//firstName.getText().toString());
            p.setLastName("Hi");//lastName.getText().toString());
            //((EditText)findViewById(android.R.id.text1)).setText("This the tune bada bing bada boom");
        }
    });
}
```

}

`
and here's my XML code

```
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width ="fill_parent"
android:layout_height = "fill_parent">
<TableLayout 
android:id="@+id/details"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical" 
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

<TableRow>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/firstName" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:ems="10" 
/>
</TableRow>
<TableRow>
<TextView
android:id="@+id/textView2"
android:layout_width = "wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="@string/lastName" />
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText2"
     />
</TableRow>
<TableRow>
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/Save" />
</TableRow>
</TableLayout>

<ListView
 android:id = "@+id/listView1"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
 android:layout_above="@id/details"
 />

</RelativeLayout>

`
```

Here's my error output

```
06-12 00:32:44.871: D/AndroidRuntime(30530): Shutting down VM
06-12 00:32:44.871: W/dalvikvm(30530): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a3b1f8)
06-12 00:32:44.879: E/AndroidRuntime(30530): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-12 00:32:44.879: E/AndroidRuntime(30530): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{matthews.zack.test/matthews.zack.test._testActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-12 00:32:44.879: E/AndroidRuntime(30530):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1956)
06-12 00:32:44.879: E/AndroidRuntime(30530):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
06-12 00:32:44.879: E/AndroidRuntime(30530):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
06-12 00:32:44.879: E/AndroidRuntime(30530):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
06-12 00:32:44.879: E/AndroidRuntime(30530):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-12 00:32:44.879: E/AndroidRuntime(30530):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-12 00:32:44.879: E/AndroidRuntime(30530):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
06-12 00:32:44.879: E/AndroidRuntime(30530):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-12 00:32:44.879: E/AndroidRuntime(30530):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-12 00:32:44.879: E/AndroidRuntime(30530):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:787)
06-12 00:32:44.879: E/AndroidRuntime(30530):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:554)
06-12 00:32:44.879: E/AndroidRuntime(30530):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-12 00:32:44.879: E/AndroidRuntime(30530): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-12 00:32:44.879: E/AndroidRuntime(30530):    at matthews.zack.test._testActivity.onInitialize(_testActivity.java:24)
06-12 00:32:44.879: E/AndroidRuntime(30530):    at matthews.zack.test._testActivity.onCreate(_testActivity.java:18)
06-12 00:32:44.879: E/AndroidRuntime(30530):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
06-12 00:32:44.879: E/AndroidRuntime(30530):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
06-12 00:32:44.879: E/AndroidRuntime(30530):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1920)
06-12 00:32:44.879: E/AndroidRuntime(30530):    ... 11 more
```

It's a bit frustrating that android will force close without telling me the exception. I would appreciate the help. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the mistake:

```
save = (Button)findViewById(android.R.id.button1);
```

You better do something like that:

```
save = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
```

And import the right R file:

```
import com.yournamespace.R;
```

Comment: When I try to import R like you describe it says it can't find my namepsace. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: When you created your app, you provided a "Package Name" with your application name. That's what I call your "namespace". So in my last line in my previous answer, you must replace "yournamespace" by the one you choose at the beginning.
Yours is "matthews.zack.test", so the import can be:`import matthews.zack.R;`

Comment: Delete this import line, and then mouse-over on the error in your code, quick-fix will show you two import, don't choose the "com.android.R".

Answer (score 6):

You're searching the `Button` using a wrong `id`. It should be:

```
save = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
```

Also, you're doing the same thing for the `EditText`. Modify it like this:

```
EditText firstName = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.text1);
EditText lastName = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.text2);
```

The only time when you would use `android.R.layout.some_id_here` is when you're using a framework defined `id`(for example you would use `android.R.id.list` for a `ListView` element used in a layout in a `ListActivity`).

Comment: When I try to import the correct R it doesn't have my namespace in android. How should I import that?

Comment: @Zack_074 If your using Eclipse as an IDE then simply do `CTRL + SHIFT + O` and pick the option **without** `android.R`.

Comment: Ctrl + shift + 0 didn't do anything

Comment: @Zack_074 The letter is `O` (from *Orbit*), `CTRL + SHIFT+ O`.

Answer (score 5):

> It's a bit frustrating that android will force close without telling me the exception.

It's right there in the log, its a `java.lang.RuntimeException` and further says

> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException

You are using `findViewById` with an *id* not defined in your layout. The function cannot find any view with that id and returns null. You later try to dereference such null and hence the `NullPointerException` exception.

Answer (score 3):

`android.R.id.button1` should be `R.id.button1`